# Buy historcal tweets for a specific period and specific keyword in Arabic

Tags: twitter, gnip

I want to buy data from twitter or any other source that can sell twitter data legally. I want all tweets that mention a specific keyword in the last six months. I want them to make analysis for a research purpose.

It seems that plan were changed in recent days for twitter and Gnip.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP seems to have mistaken Stack Overflow for Twitter's sales department.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend going to https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tutorials/one-time-historical-powertrack-jobs.html.

It'll ask you to submit the query rules you're looking for and the duration of time. Once that's set up, a Twitter employee should reach out with an estimate.